# Google Data Studio: Connect to multiple schemas in multi-tenant postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, multi-tenant, business-intelligence, looker-studio

I have a multi-tenant database in postgres. So, I have one schema per customer and each schema has a fixed set of tables.
When I connect to the DB using Google Data Studio(GDS), I only see the table names without their associated schema.
How do I connect to tables belonging to one or more schemas?
Also, what do I do if my tables have more than 700k rows, as GDS has a limit on number of rows that can be queried right?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the "Custom Query" option instead of the basic table selection if you need anything more complex.

Regarding the row limit. I wasn't aware of the limit, but if that is true I'd suggest using the Custom Query to pre-group your rows in the query into whatever makes sense...days...months...etc to bring the row count down.

Data Studio will likely choke on anywhere near that many rows and make for a horrible user experience. Let Postgres do as much of the heavy lifting as you can.

Comment: So, using the custom query, I can select tables across schemas right? Also, how is such a multi-tenant setup used for reporting aggregates across multiple schemas? I presume this is a common set-up for many people and there must be a way to aggregate data across all schemas?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you are overestimating Data Studio's abilities. Data Studio's common user base is people that want to connect Google Analytics and pre-baked data sources into a user-friendly report. I don't believe aggregating data across schema is a common use case in DS.

Anything that you can do with a Postgres query should be possible in Data Studio but that's also the limitation. There is a concept of "Blended Data" in Data Studio where you can essentially join one or more data sources (queries) if you can't get all of your data in one query so you might look into that.

Comment: Apart from data studio, is there a common technique used to aggregate data across schemas? Could be direct SQL or any other BI tool if you have had any experience.

Comment: It would probably be best to ask that in a separate question with more detail on the database structures and what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

*Answering only: "what do I do if my tables have more than 700k rows, as GDS has a limit on number of rows that can be queried right?"*

Not exactly. The limit is on the number of rows returned, not the amount of rows queried. And that matters since Data Studio will almost always push down queries to connectors.

Here's an example: Lets say you have a purchase table in a PostgreSQL db with 1M+ rows where each record is a purchase event. You add this table as a data source in your report and add a bar chart that shows average purchase by customer type. Let's say you have 12 customer types. Data Studio will then push down the `GROUP BY` clause to the PostgreSQL db. Thus, your result will have only 12 rows of data instead of 1M+. In most chart types, Data Studio will aggregate or page the results thus issuing a query statement that limits the number of rows returned.

You will only run into the limit if you end up creating a scenario where Data Studio cannot issue an aggregation or paging over the query results or if the aggregated results cross the row limit.